# Is there a database somewhere of common lists?

Tags: datasets, resource-request

I'm looking for a database or some machine readable document that contains common ordered lists or common short sets. e.g:

```
{January, February, March,...}
{Monday, Tuesday, ....}
{Red, Orange, Yellow,...}
{1,2,3,4,...}
{one, two, three, four,...}
{Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars,...}
{I, II, III, IV, V, VI,...}
{Aquarius, Pisces, Aries,...}
{ein, zwei, drei, ...}
{Happy, Sneezy, Dopey, ...}
{Dasher, Dancer, Prancer, Vixen ,...}
{John, Paul, George, Ringo}
{20, 1, 18, 4, 13, 6, ...}
{Alabama, Alaska, Arizona, Arkansas, California,...}
{Washington, Adams, Jefferson, ...}
{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,...}
{A,E,I,O,U}
{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,...}
{triangle, square, pentagon, hexagon,...}
{first, second, third, fourth, fifth,...}
{tetrahedron, cube, octohedron, icosohedron, dodecahedron}
{autumn, winter, spring, summer}
{to, be, or, not, to, be, that, is, the, question}
...
```

One use is for creating an AI that can solve codes or predict the next thing in a sequence.

Comment: I've provisionally added a new tag for "resource-requests" because I can see how access to such the types of datasets you're looking for could be useful to others looking to create or train algorithms.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic, in disagreement with the current close-vote. In fact, one of the most important open point in AI is how an AI system can establish relations between concepts. In fact, this one is on-topic, 99% of the question about neural net implementations are not.

Comment: [Questions asking for datasets or tools, such as software libraries or APIs, are off-topic here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We focus on the **theoretical, social** and **philosophical** aspects of artificial intelligence (so this excludes recommendations of software libraries). If you're looking for software recommendations, you should ask your question here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. If you're looking for datasets, you probably should ask it on [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

So here’s a couple quick resources that i could think of.  First of all, you could look at this,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lists_of_lists

It has classics such accidents,  hospitals in Asia, or even a list of famous resignations. It’s easentially a list of random lists of things.  It may not owner cover your requirement for sequences but it’ll help with small subsets of lists.

As for sequences, you could always check out,

https://oeis.org

It’s pretty much a list of official mathematical sequences.  It’s got everything from the Fibonacci sequence to esoteric sequences you’ve never heard of.